# LU Decomposistion Using javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I have tried to find the LU Decomposition code written in JS. I found a numeric.js but its buggy. Is there any source available in JavaScript?

I have to try the webworks for the LU Decomposition. But I'm not able to find any available code.

I just included the the numeric.js into my HTML page.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="numeric-1.2.6.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    lu = numeric.cLU([[1,2,4],[3,8,14],[2,6,13]]);
    console.log(lu);
  </script>
```

In the console I got the following error:

```
 RangeError: invalid array length
 var n = s[k], ret = Array(n), i;
```

When I try to debug the code in the following function:

```
 numeric.cLU = function LU(A)
```

there was problem in the following lines:

```
 left = numeric.rep([m],Infinity),
 right = numeric.rep([m],-Infinity);
```

I replaced the Infinity with the 0. Then I got error that V is undefined at this line.

```
 for(k=0;k<p;k++) { i = I[k]; U[i][J[k]-left[i]] = V[k]; }
```

that what I found. May be I'm doing something wrong.  As I'm newbie to LU.

Comment: is there any particular reason you want to use JavaScript?

Comment: @JonahWilliams Maybe he likes it? What's the point of your question?

Comment: According to `numeric.js` [unit tests page](http://www.numericjs.com/report.html), LU test is passing. Can you show us the case you deemed "buggy"?

Comment: @Baran please edit that into the question, reasonably formatted.

Comment: Update the question @BartekBanachewicz

Comment: I don't really have the background to understand it all, but you seem to have a dense matrix, but you're using what seems to be the banded matrix function `numeric.cLU`; use `numeric.LU` instead, see if it picks up.

Comment: @Amadan it works But I need the Lower and Upper Only it returns LU and P